# Mapbox-gl only displaying half the container

Tags: angular, mapbox-gl

I'm trying to get ngx-mapbox-gl to display a map in an angular app, but the map is only displaying in half the div. Have played with multiple settings and html tweaks, but cannot get more than half a map to display. Here is the map.component.html file:

```
    <div class="map" ng-view flex layout-fill style="height: 100%;border: solid 1px">
      <mgl-map
           [style]="'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v9'"
           [zoom]="9"
           [center]="_center"
           (load)="loadMap($event)"
       >
       </mgl-map> 
     </div>
```

and the map.component.scss:

```
     @import 'mapbox-gl/dist/mapbox-gl.css';

     .mapboxgl-canvas {
       position: fixed !important;
       height: 100% !important;
}
```

map.component.ts:

```
 import { Component, OnInit, Input, Output, EventEmitter, OnChanges } from      '@angular/core';

 import { LngLat, Map } from 'mapbox-gl';

 @Component({
   selector: 'app-map',
   templateUrl: './map.component.html',
   styleUrls: ['./map.component.scss'],
 })

 export class DisplayMapComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {
   map: Map;

   _center: LngLat;

   //refs
   _mapRef: Map;

   @Output()
   centerChange: EventEmitter<LngLat> =  new EventEmitter;

   @Input()
   set zoom(z: number) {
     this._zoom = z;
     if(this.index === 0) {
       this.zoomChange.emit(this._zoom);
     }
   }
   @Output()
   zoomChange : EventEmitter<number> = new EventEmitter;
   _zoom: number;

   @Input()
   index: number;

   constructor() { }

   ngOnInit() {
     this.zoom = 11;
     this._center = new LngLat( -121.31209, 37.449904  );
     console.log('this._center: ', this._center);
   }

   ngOnChanges(changes) {
     console.log('changes: ', changes);
     if (!changes) {
       return;
     }

   }

   loadMap( map: Map) {
     console.log("Initializing map, _center: ", this._center);
     console.log("map: ", map);
     this._mapRef = map;
     console.log("Loading map data");
     this._center = map.getCenter();
     console.log('this._center from map: ', this._center);
   }

 }
```

app.module.ts:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { LocalStorageService } from './services/local-storage.service';
import { MatToolbarModule, MatMenuModule, MatIconModule, MatListModule, MatGridListModule, MatButtonModule, MatCardModule } from '@angular/material'; 
import { MatSidenavModule } from '@angular/material/sidenav';
import { FlexLayoutModule } from '@angular/flex-layout';
import { StorageServiceModule } from 'angular-webstorage-service';

//mapbox imports
import { NgxMapboxGLModule } from 'ngx-mapbox-gl';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HeaderComponent } from './components/header/header.component';
import { DisplayMapComponent } from './components/map/map.component';
import { NavbarComponent } from './components/navbar/navbar.component';
import { LayoutModule } from '@angular/cdk/layout';
import { SettingsContainerComponent } from './components/settings-    container/settings-container.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HeaderComponent,
    DisplayMapComponent,
    NavbarComponent,
    SettingsContainerComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
    MatSidenavModule,
    MatMenuModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatIconModule,
    FlexLayoutModule,
    LayoutModule,
    MatListModule,
    StorageServiceModule,
    NgxMapboxGLModule.withConfig({
      accessToken: '<token>', 
    }),
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Here's a screenshot of what I'm seeing:

[image]
If I remove the map,the border of the div it taking the entire window as it should. But I can't get the map to use up the entire window. Is it css or html or ts I'm doing wrong?

Thanks....

Comment: No one have any ideas?

Comment: Looks like css issue. Can you create demo in stackblitz?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do the same as it is shown in the [ngx-mapbox-gl documentation sample](https://github.com/Wykks/ngx-mapbox-gl). There is a getting started section that explains all in detail. Here is also a summary of what you need to do.

Instead of using your `.mapboxgl-canvas` style override you just need to specify this style in the `map.component.scss` file:

```
 mgl-map {
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
    }
```

Put the import of the mapbox css file `@import 'mapbox-gl/dist/mapbox-gl.css';` in the main styles.scss file of the application instead in the component file. Then it should work ok.

Also another tip. Since you are using the `@angular/flex-layout` library you can use the fxFlexFill directive on your div to make it fill all the content instead off all what you have there. Then you component html is much more clean.

```
<div fxFlexFill style="border: solid 1px">
  <mgl-map
      [style]="'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v9'"
      [zoom]="9"
      [center]="_center"
      (load)="loadMap($event)"
  >
  </mgl-map> 
</div>
```

I have created also a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngx-mapbox?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts) sample where you can see it working. If you want to see the map you need to edit the sample and add your token in the `app.module.ts`.

Comment: Wonderful!!!!!!! Thank you so much AlesD! I thought the answer would be simple, but for the life of me could not figure this one out. You are a lifesaver. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I followed the documentation and it still didn't work.
@cpeddie [issue on Github](https://github.com/Wykks/ngx-mapbox-gl/issues/98#issuecomment-495319714) did it for me:

html-

```
<mgl-map (load)="onMapLoad($event)"></mgl-map>
```

ts-

```
export class NgMapComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  // map box
  map: mapBox.Map;
...

  onMapLoad(mapinstance) {
    this.map = mapinstance;
    this.map.resize();
    console.log('resize');
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

**I have resized the map on map Load event and it worked for me**

```
loadMap( map: Map) {
 console.log("Initializing map, _center: ", this._center);
 console.log("map: ", map);
 this._mapRef = map;
 console.log("Loading map data");
 this._center = map.getCenter();
 console.log('this._center from map: ', this._center);
 // i added
 map.resize()}
```